# Calculation issue on woocommerce order-details totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a Wordpress+Woocommerce website for a client. He needs his customers to pay 30% of the cart in advance, then they start to prepare the order.

Since Woocommerce doesn't have this prepayment function built in, I decided to use a coupon, applying automatically a 70% rebate on the order total (then I will hide the coupon infos).

For a 1000€ cart, the client will see : `Total = 300€`. 
Then I'm adding a "Left to pay" line and show the result making a simple calculation in the function file: `$woocommerce->cart->subtotal - $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;`
The result is the amount of the discount : 700€ in this case.

**Problem:**
This is working perfectly on the cart and checkout page, but on the order-details page the amount of "Left to pay" is 0.

This is the code displaying the totals on the order-details template (in woocommerce\order).

```
<!-- show the totals on Order Details footer -->
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) foreach ( $totals as $total ) :
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        endforeach;

    ?>

<!-- Trying to add the Left to pay line here -->
    <?php   if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) { ?>
        <tr class="order-total">
            <th>Left to pay</th>
            <td><?php echo number_format(custom_Total_Solde(),2,'.','')."€"; ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php }; ?>
```

And here is the code I'm using on functions to calculate the amount of the "Left to pay".

```
function custom_Total_Solde() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $solde = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal - $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
    return $solde;
}
```

Anyone knows how the totals are calculated on order-details? Is it different than on the cart or the checkout?
Maybe you know in which template the order-details total labels are stored? If I can find it, maybe I can understand why my calculation doesn't work on this specific part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've checked out the cart info is cleared, so it isn't available for calculations.

You need to look into the `WC_Order` class in `includes/class-wc-order.php`.

`$order->get_total()` should tell you the total amount paid. And possibly `$order->get_total_discount()` or `$order->get_cart_discount()` would therefore be how much was left to be paid?

Or you could add some custom meta to the order when it is created in the checkout using the following hook:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $this->posted );
```

I've heard that future versions of WooCommerce will support partial payments, but until then you could also check out the [WooCommerce Deposit Plugin](http://www.limeplugins.com/woocommerce-deposit-plugin/)

PS- `global $woocommerce` is soft-deprecated, so you should get used to using `WC()` in its place.

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot! I was looking around that but not sure why `$order->get_cart_discount()` didn't worked in my functions. I placed it directly on the php template and it works. I've seen this Deposit plugin but I wanted to keep the code as simple and light as possible. Thanks for the info about `global $woocommerce`, can you tell me how to use `WC()` in my function?(I'm still learning php)

Comment: You're welcome. `get_cart_discount()` is a class method so it needs a class object( the `$order` variable in this case ) to work on. `$order` is available in the template, but you'd need to create a `$order = new WC_Order($order_id)` to use it in the functions. You use `WC()` by simply replacing all your instances of `$woocommerce` with `WC()`. ex: `$woocommerce->cart` becomes `WC()->cart`.